# Change default document name for custom content type template

Tags: 2013

Does anyone know how to change this file name?

[image]

Basically we have a template that users will need to create and modify every two months. So I added it as a custom content type by following this guide
[office support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-27eb6551-9867-4201-a819-620c5658a60f)

But now I would like it to automatically save as something like:

> INSERTMONTH_filename.doc

Or something similar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using InfoPath for the custom template as the article you linked is, underneath Fields on the bottom right it should say " Manage Data Connections," choose this.
2. If you already have a Data Connection choose to "Modify it" or Create a new one by providing the link to your SharePoint site library/list where this form and information reside.
3. Where it says File Name: Click on the (Fx) symbol and here you have choices to automatically name the form the date it was created, or any of the fields , or Both by using "Concat" this will work once you publish it.

You can choose in the same menu to allow overwrite if the file with that name exists or not.